# I'm connecting to the same table twice with a MySQL query, is there any other solution?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I get the number of users participating in the contest with query number 1, and the number of designs participating in the contest with query number 2. It reaches the same table in 2 queries. Can I do this with a single query or how should it be?

```
$totalDesigner= DB::getVar('SELECT Count(DISTINCT u_id) FROM race where yid=?',array(1));

$totalDesign= DB::getVar('SELECT Count(DISTINCT d_id) FROM race where yid=?',array(1));
```

Will it be the right way to fall into a single query or are the 2 existing queries more efficient?

Comment: I am not sure what tool or library you are using, so I can only give a generic answer.  In terms of MySQL, you can just do `select count(u_id), count(d_id) from table `.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::get('SELECT Count(DISTINCT uye) as tasarimcilar, Count(DISTINCT id) as tasarimlar FROM yarisanlar where yid=?',array($yarisma->id));
```

this is how i solved it thanks